# I'm having a little trouble with LESS and Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I've finally decided that I'd like to learn LESS and so far I'm absolutely loving it. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I'm having a little bit of trouble when it comes to creating containers and rows in my LESS documents.

A simple HTML example:

```
<header>
    <article>...</article>
    <aside>...</aside>
</header>
```

My LESS would be:

```
 header
    .container-fixed();
    .make-row();
    article {
    .make-md-column(6);
    }
    aside {
    .make-md-column(6);
    }
 header
```

I'm keeping my header outside of the container because I'd like the background to stretch 100% wide. I keep getting an error that says "ParseError: Unrecogonized input on line 2, columns 26" and it's pointing to the .container-fixed(); and .make-row();.

I'm no whiz at this stuff but I'm sure there's something super simple I'm just not understanding. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap curly braces around `header`

```
header {
    .container-fixed();
    .make-row();
        article {
            .make-md-column(6);
        }
        aside {
            .make-md-column(6);
        }
}
```

Comment: Okay, my code looks just like this and the container is still spanning the entire width of my page. Is there a variable somewhere that I have to define that I'm missing? When I add a .container in the HTML it's working fine. It's a bit frustrating because I know the answer is so simple. It just hasn't clicked yet...

Comment: As long as you're importing `bootstrap.less` into the LESS file you created it should work.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but bare with me here. I have my working folder in WinLESS and have only bootstrap.less ticked. I've also created a style.less file and added `@import "style.less";` to my bootstrap.less file. Any changes that I make to the example code I posted above, (changing the column widths for example) are working fine. Everything works but the .container-fixed(); class.

Comment: The code of @stiga compiles right for me. Do you still got an error? or will the effect of  `.container-fixed();` not as expect? Note `.container-fixed();` is not a class but a mixin

Comment: I'm at work right now but I'm going to try this when I get home. I'll keep you updated. I appreciate all the help!